# Replace quotes using lazy simple serde hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Hi I am dealing with many files which has quotes in the data as shown below.

"ID"|"STUDENT"|"GRADE"
"123"|"John"|"9.7"
"132"|"Johny"|"8.7"
"143"|"Ronny"|"8.17"

I would like to remove quotes from data can you please let me know how it can be done. If at all using any built in serdes will be helpfull. Since I am dealing with many such file.

Answer (score 1):

Load this data as such into a temp hive table . Then use regex_replace() function while inserting into your table.

steps :

1. load data into a temp table with similar schema.
2. Insert overwrite into the final table with regex_replace().

   ```
   insert overwrite table select    regexp_replace(COLUMN_NAME_1,"\"",""),regexp_replace(COLUMN_NAME_2,"\"","") from temp_hive_table;
   ```

**Updated :**

For many files.

1. Define the temp table as an external table.
2. Copy all your source files to this hdfs path.
3. Do insert overwrite with regex_replace() into the desired table.

Hope this approach helps.

Comment: This approach will help if we are doing this for one file, But if you have many files with the same format. It will not be feasible.

Comment: is it one file per table .right?Then this would be fine else , I am only thinking of some shell/perl script .

Comment: No the file sizes will grow eventually and having hunderds of GB's to SED in Unix for many files will not help too. I hope you understood the jinx I am in and the reason why I was preferring any built in SerDe.

Comment: I dint still get it . You are using 1 source file for a table right ?

Comment: No Many files for different tables